# Trying to prove a floor function is surjective (onto)

Tags: proof-writing, proof-explanation

$f : \Bbb R\to \Bbb Z$  where $x$ is an element of $\Bbb R$,
$f(x) = \mathrm{floor}(2x)$

I am trying to prove that this function is onto, it pretty clearly is surjective since the floor of any $2x$ maps to each and every integer, but I don't know how to prove it per se.

All of the examples of proving something is onto suggests using algebra to find an element from the co domain maps back to the domain but this function does not seem to work that way.

I also understand that if $n = \mathrm{floor}(2x)$ then $n \le 2x < n + 1$ but I'm not quite sure how to apply this

Thanks.

Comment: For every $n\in\Bbb Z$, the number $x:=n/2\in\Bbb R$ maps to $f(x)=n$. What more do you need?

Comment: The map $g:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}:x\mapsto 2x$ is clearly surjective and the map $h:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow \mathbb{Z}:x\mapsto \lfloor x\rfloor$ is also surjective (Indeed, $h(z)=z$ for all $z\in \mathbb{Z}$). Notice that $f=h\circ g$ is a the composition of surjective functions and thus also surjective. 

Or you know, just do the easy thing as above.